# Parameterize the number of iterations in the Gremlin pageRank step

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

As far as I understand gremlin pageRank step (`g.V().pageRank()`) runs a PageRank vertex program with 30 iterations.

Is it possible to change the max number of iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
g.V().pageRank().times(5)
```

There's an example of this in the Apache TinkerPop [docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#pagerankvertexprogram):

```
gremlin> g.V().pageRank().by('pageRank').times(5).order().by('pageRank').valueMap()
==>[pageRank:[0.15000000000000002],name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[pageRank:[0.15000000000000002],name:[peter],age:[35]]
==>[pageRank:[0.19250000000000003],name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[pageRank:[0.19250000000000003],name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[pageRank:[0.23181250000000003],name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[pageRank:[0.4018125],name:[lop],lang:[java]]
```